# Animated population of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` stuffed with a collection of `CardView`. My code is essentially the code on [this official](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/material/lists-cards.html) article, and works fine, so there is no need to post my code here. Is on there.

It's looks like the following:

```
+------------------------------+
| +------------+ +------------+ |
| |   card 1   | |            | |
| +------------+ +------------+ |
| +------------+ +------------+ |
| |            | |            | |
| +------------+ +------------+ |
| +------------+ +------------+ |
| |            | |            | |
| +------------+ +------------+ |
| +------------+ +------------+ |
| |            | |   card N   | |
| +------------+ +------------+ |
+-------------------------------+
```

All **CardViews** are shown at the same time, as expected.

But what I want is that the views are displayed one by one from outside the view up to it's normal position.

```
+-------------------------------+         +-------------------------------+
| +------------+                |         | +------------+ +------------+ |
| |   card 1   |                |         | |   card 1   | |   card 2   | |
| +------------+                |         | +------------+ +------------+ |
|                      ^        |         |                               |
|                      |        |         |                               |
|                      |        |         |                               |
|                      |        |         |                               |
|                      |        |         |       ^                       |
|                      |        |         |       |                       |
|                      |        |         |       |                       |
|                      |        |         |       |                       |
|                      |        |         |       |                       |
+----------------------|--------+         +-------|-----------------------+
                  ------------+             +------------+ 
                 |   card 2   |             |   card 3   |   
                 +------------+             +------------+
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you find anything? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom item animator (or extend default one) and override `animateAdd` such that the card will animate from below the screen. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#animateAdd(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) for details. Failing to implement it properly may cause losing ViewHolders so you should be careful.

The best way to run the animation is to create an animator that will animate `translationY` from `recyclerView.getHeight()` to 0. You can check [DefaultItemAnimator](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator.java) for references.

Btw, in the first layout pass, RecyclerView will not animate Views because it looks weird to fade in everything. To overcome it, initially keep your adapter empty and after the first layout pass, add your items (you can use a handler and defer adding items to your adapter).

Btw, RecyclerView does not 'yet' support animating views while scrolling so `animateAdd` will not be called when new items are added while list is scrolled by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating custom ItemAnimators as in below project.

https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/RecyclerViewItemAnimators

Comment: Unfortunately, while the population works well, when done scrolling, the cardview get misplaced or disappear soon, this library still has some issues.